# Can I host a custom site using html, css, and js through git hub pages without using a Jekyll theme?

Tags: javascript, jekyll, github-pages

So I'm trying to setup a portfolio page through Github pages, but want to use custom code instead of a Jekyll theme. My page is HTML, CSS, and JS and haven't found a solid solution yet. Is this possible and, if so, how do I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

All you have to do is name your `html` file as `index.html` and publish it to the appropriate repository.

---

You have 2 options:

1. You either push your files in a `gh-pages` branch of the repository of your choice, if you have already setup your `username.github.io` or
2. You can go ahead and create a new reportsitory named `username.github.io` and push the code to the `master` branch.

---

Here's a [link to a github help article](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

---

#### EDIT :

Specifically [THIS](https://pages.github.com/) 5-step tutorial describes exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: So I pushed my html, css, and javascript and I'm getting a 404 page. The repository is gooshtie.github.io. Could you by any chance take a look at it?

Comment: Can you remove this line: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo copy.png">` and try again? Make sure you empty cache and hard reload after you pushed again

Comment: Deleted and pushed, but still 404

Comment: Heyyy, nvm its working, i think it just needed a sec, thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem mate, it does take a while for github to update gh-pages. If my answer did it, please do accept it

Comment: Nice website btw!

Comment: Thanks! Still gonna mess with it some more, appreciate the help!

Comment: I had to add a `.nojekyll` file to bypass jekyll.